# Issue with conditional formatting cell range based on exact match text in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, text, conditional-formatting, countif, exact-match

We track workshop registrations in a google sheet and I'm trying to conditionally format a range of cells (A7:P14) based on the text in cell E7 (Eng DLO, Eng TBC, Sp DLO, Sp TBC).

I used the formula

```
=COUNTIF($E7:$E, "Eng DLO")
```

and A7:S14 turned the selected color (light purple). When I then added conditional formatting to turn dark purple with the formula

```
=COUNTIF($E7:$E, "Eng TBC")
```

the color wouldn't change when I changed the value in E7 from Eng DLO to Eng TBC.

I know the issue is that I need it to EXACTLY MATCH the text and I tried incorporating EXACT into the COUNTIF formula, but it would only highlight E7 or just A7:P7 instead of the whole selected range in the conditional format (A7:P14).

Here is a sample sheet with what I am hoping it will eventually look like once I get the conditional formatting to actually work (I removed the conditional formatting). https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bn9FVTHE1OO49p4PKo6j0Qd3c0NX6pUq3vp0pHFNGVI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Got a couple other issues here:

1. The `7` is a floating reference, so you need to fix it with `$`. This is the reason your formula isn't working. In the next row, it would start counting in cell E8. With the `$`, it works, but less efficiently than it could, which brings me to point 2.
2. If you're only referencing one cell, just check for equality against that one cell.

To the `Eng TBC`, you would use

```
=EXACT($E$7, "Eng TBC")
```

---

Just to demonstrate a point, without the dollar sign, the next rows cells would have been checking against this:

```
=EXACT($E8, "Eng TBC")
```

Which of course would have been empty.

---

### A More Flexible Solution

Since you probably don't want to keep having to reformat per set of cells, you can use a `ROW`-based approach to tackle the issue. This one, for example, assumes 8 seats per group.

```
=EXACT("Eng DLO",INDIRECT("E"&(8 * INT((ROW() - 7) / 8) + 7)))
```

Every 8 rows, it references the next multiple of 7. (Yes, `INT` is `FLOOR`, but shorter.)

Comment: Thank you that helped with one of the issues. Now the issue I'm having is that I want to apply this conditional formatting throughout the sheet, but because of the absolute reference, when I pasted conditional formatting to the next 8 rows, it adjusted the color based on E7 instead of E15 (I added the conditional formatting with your formula to the test sheet so you can see what I mean). I'd rather not have to conditionally format each section of rows as that would be very time consuming. Is there an easy tweak so that the conditional formatting can be pasted/applied throughout?

Comment: @Bri I added a solution assuming 8 seats per set. Does that work for you, or do you need something better?

Comment: I plugged in your formula to the test sheet for the Eng DLO conditional formatting, but it changed the formatting in rows 15-22 and the formatting won't change based on the selection in cell E15, but still changes based on the selection in E7.